# Fabric.js Ellipse properties not updated in Json

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

When I change the height and the width from an ellipse in the canvas with the handlers and I see the json from the modified ellipse, is see that `height`, `width`, `rx` and `ry` are not updated in the json.  Also after `setCoords()` and `canvas.renderAll()`.

How to update this information?

```
canvas.on('object:modified', modifiedHandler);

var modifiedHandler = function (evt) {
  var modifiedObject = evt.target;
  modifiedObject.setCoords(); 
  canvas.renderAll();

  console.log("object",JSON.stringify(canvas));
  
  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you modify an object on the canvas using its handlers, the object's properties are not automatically updated in the object's JSON representation. You need to explicitly update the object's properties in the JSON representation after modifying the object.

```
var modifiedHandler = function (evt) {
  var modifiedObject = evt.target;
  modifiedObject.setCoords(); 
  canvas.renderAll();

  console.log("object",JSON.stringify(modifiedObject.toJSON()));
};
```